# Circular polarizer rotation

Tags: optics, polarization, light-emitting-diodes

If I use a circular polarizer to a uniformly illuminated white LED light and rotate it I observe a change in intensity accross the wavelengths. Especially towards the blue side. Its almost to the effect of blue tint.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I circularly polarize a white LED light and avoid this effect?

Comment: Rotating a circular polarizer causes changes?  That's peculiar.

Comment: This question does not provide sufficient information to be answerable.

Comment: Usually these filters will state a bandwidth over which they work effectively in their datasheet. For filters designed for the visible, the lower end of the wavelength range is usually 400nm, and on the blue side of an LED light you'll be in that ballpark too, so your filter will likely not work as expected in that wavelength range. But as Emilio pointed out above, there isn't enough info in your question to give a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A white LED is indeed a blue led with a phosphor coating tipically, so its spectrum has two peaks: one in the blue range (very intense) and another in the yellow range (less intense). With a polarizer you're even more reducing the intensity of both peaks.

Comment: yes correct. White LED has 2 regions. However, is there a way to circularly polarize white LED spectrum without having the change in intensity while rotating the polarizer. As you rotate the intensity of the blue varies with the rotation degree.

Comment: That depends on the properties of the light emitted from the phosphor. You should check the datasheet of the LED